# What does error mean in this context?

Tags: feature-selection, definition

In the paper:
Avrim L. Blum and Pat Langley. 1997. Selection of relevant features and examples in machine learning. Artif. Intell. 97, 1-2 (December 1997), 245-271.

are several definitions of the term relevance.

In Definition 4 it says

> Given a sample of data $S$ and a set of concepts $C$, let $r(S,C)$ be
>   the number of features relevant using Definition 1 to a concept in $C$
>   that, out of all those whose error over $S$ is least, has the fewest
>   relevant features.

A view lines later...

> The above notions of relevance are independent of the specific
>   learning algorithm being used. There is no guarantee that just because
>   a feature is relevant, it will necessarily be useful to an algorithm (or vice versa).

What does error in definition 4 mean in this context? I first thought he refered to the classifier error but then it says those definitions are independent of a learning algorithm.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a proper reference to the paper you quote?

Comment: I have edited the question.